# Python type hint in design pattern Abstract Factory

Tags: python

assuming the abstract class

```
class Exchange(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_account_balance(self, page_source: str) -> float | tuple[float, str]:
        """return the account balance as float"""
```

I then have two exchanges classes, one that returns:
`get_account_balance(self, page_source: str) -> float:`
and another one that returns:
`get_account_balance(self, page_source: str) -> tuple[float, str]:`

My question is, is it ok to define the signature of the class in the abstract class `Exchange(ABC)` as `get_account_balance(self, page_source: str) -> float | tuple[float, str]` or should I define the type hint in a different way?

Comment: The real question is why does one of the subclasses return a different data type? Now every time your code wants to call `get_account_balance` on any kind of `Exchange`, it needs to check whether it's the "special" `Exchange` subclass  that returns the different data type. Why not return a mock value for the string, like `""`, and type hint `Exchange` and all of its subclasses with `-> tuple[float, str]`?

Comment: why is tuple[foloat, str]?

Comment: I think you mean Union, right?

Comment: float | union(float, str) -> float | float | str -> float | str

Comment: I think this would be a case for making `Exchange` generic in the return type rather than narrowing a union type in the subclasses.

Comment: @jfaccioni you would suggest adding something like `mock = ""` to the subclasses that don't need the `str` value and in the `get_account_balance` `return  account_balance, mock` so that I can use the `-> tuple[float, str]` everywhere. Did I get you right?

Comment: @64rl0 In doing so, you may eliminate the need to *have* two separate subclasses. Just the `tuple[float, str]` version, and instances that don't have any other relevant string to use can use `""` by default.

Comment: Or, perhaps this should not be a single method in the first place. `get_account_balance(...) -> float` and `get_annotated_account_balance(...) -> tuple[float, str]` would make more sense. It also seems that one could be defined in terms of the other as necessary.

Comment: @64rl0 yes, and just to be clear, this is not about type-hinting as much as it is about consistency. If you don't standarize the return value of `get_account_balance` across all subclasses, any code expected to work with `Exchange` and its subclasses suddenly needs to test the return type of `exchange.get_account_balance()` calls. It's much easier to be consistent, so that you're able to *rely* on the return type of `get_account_balance` for whatever `Exchange` subclass that you use.

Comment: If you really need both return types for different use cases, consider creating a second method that returns essentially the same data, but as `float` instead of `tuple[float, str]`.